# Find $f(2^2)$ in given condition

Tags: continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function in  $[1,3]$  defined for all $x$ belonging to $ R $. If $f(x)$ take rational values for all $x$ belonging to R and $f(2)=198$ then $f(2^2)$

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and what you're having trouble with? This is essentially a very standard exercise in applying some theorem about intermediate values.

Comment: I really don't get what to do.

Comment: i dont think there is one solution , question is incomplete for ex: take $f(x)=198$ , for all $x$ or $f(x)= 196+x$ and so on. i would suggest typing the whole question from whichever source you are typing, and post what ideas you had when you saw the question

Comment: Ok, then. My crystal ball says that you got this in a course immediately after talking about a theorem that says the words "intermediate value." If not, then tell us where you found this problem.

Comment: @avz2611 Does $196 + x$ have only rational outputs?

Comment: @T.Bongers it never said anything about rational outputs , it said function is capable of taking rational inputs

Comment: @avz2611 The question says that $f$ takes rational values for all inputs.

Comment: ah i misunderstood the question you are right

Comment: I found it in my book

Comment: The solution is continuous in [1,3]

Comment: Sorry function is continuous in [1,3]

Answer (score 1):

I guess f(4)=198 also, bechause if it were any other value, then by the intermidiate value theorem, it would take all values between 198 and said other value.
I don't, however, understand why f is only given to be continious in [1;3] when we are asked about f(4)